# how to create xpath usingdiv tag, textarea and placeholder

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code of HTML:

```
<div class="uk-form-row"> 
<textarea ng-model="attribute.description[0].text" 
cols="30" rows="3" placeholder="Description" class="uk-form-width-medium ng-
pristine ng-valid ng-touched chromeXpathFinder chromeXpathFinder0">
 </textarea> 
</div>
```

I tried to create the following xpath but it doesn't work:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='uk-form-row']//textarea[@placeholder='Description']")).sendKeys("Hello description");
```

Could you please guide me on the right solution?

The exception it throws is :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
```

Comment: use ExplicitWait until element get visible.

Comment: ohk i thought there was problem with my Xpath . Thanku ! :)

Comment: i am sorry i cannot share the credentials as they belong to a third party. but for your information my element is in a form... further inside several div elements.. form element is as follows: <form class="uk-form uk-form-stacked ng-valid ng-scope ng-valid-max-tags ng-valid-min-tags ng-valid-leftover-text ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" ng-controller="createAttributeCtrl">

Comment: USe this xpath //textarea[@placeholder='Description'][@class='uk-form-width-medium ng-
pristine ng-valid ng-touched chromeXpathFinder chromeXpathFinder0']

Comment: i shows chromeXpathfinder because i am using an extension in chrome called chromeXpathFinder!

Answer (score 1):

Use some wait until your element get visible and then send the text
Use `ExplicitWait` like below

```
WebElement description = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='uk-form-row']//textarea[@placeholder='Description']"));

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(description));
description.sendKeys("Text");
```

Comment: on executing this code , it shows the following error : Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 60 seconds waiting for visibility of [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (10cc89654fd2bd255492c92792de55c3)] -> xpath: //div[@class='uk-form-row']//textarea[@placeholder='Description']]

Comment: is your element in iframe ?

Comment: can u share site url ?

Comment: I can share the url but not the credentials.. https://q-apis-two.iot-build.qa.covapp.io/#/dashboard

Comment: my element is in a form... further inside several div elements.. form element is as follows: <form class="uk-form uk-form-stacked ng-valid ng-scope ng-valid-max-tags ng-valid-min-tags ng-valid-leftover-text ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" ng-controller="createAttributeCtrl">

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath

```
//textarea[@placeholder='Description'][@class='uk-form-width-medium ng-
pristine ng-valid ng-touched chromeXpathFinder chromeXpathFinder0']
```

Try this too

```
 //textarea[@placeholder='Description']
```

Comment: i shows chromeXpathfinder because i am using an extension in chrome called chromeXpathFinder!

Comment: Then it is sure xpath is not correct, But in my system it is worked

Comment: how did it work in your system? do you have the credentials?